# PhP Associative Array displayed in a Table

Tags: php, associative-array

I am VERY new to PhP. Quick question that I am having trouble finding the answer to online, although I am sure most of you will quickly know the answer. I have the following code creating an associative array and then I am trying to display it in a table. I know there are easier ways to display it in a table like a foreach loop, but I would like to learn this method first :

```
class CarDealer extends Company {

var $navbar_array = array();

 function  create_navbar_array ( )  {
    $mainurl = $this->company_url;   // get the main url address of this web page
    $this->navbar_array = array( "Home Page"=>"$mainurl?whichpage=home", "Sales"=>"$mainurl?whichpage=sales",
       "Support" => "$mainurl?whichpage=support", "Contacts" => "$mainurl?whichpage=contact" );
 }

function getLeftNavBar() {
$data ="<table border='1' style='background-color:yellow; width:35%'>";
$data .="<tr><td>$this->navbar_array['Home Page']</td></tr>";
$data .="<tr><td>$this->navbar_array['Sales']</td></tr>";
$data .="<tr><td>$this->navbar_array['Support']</td></tr>";
$data .="<tr><td>$this->navbar_array['Contacts']</td></tr>";
$data .="</table>";
return $data;
}

}
```

Later in my code I create an object for my class and then try to print the table. Unfortunately I am just getting an output of things like Array['Home Page'].

```
$carobject = new CarDealer();

$carobject->create_navbar_array();
print $carobject->getLeftNavBar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass array values to the function try

```
class extends Company {

var $navbar_array = array();

 function  create_navbar_array ( )  {
    $mainurl = $this->company_url;   // get the main url address of this web page
    $this->navbar_array = array( "Home Page"=>"$mainurl?whichpage=home", "Sales"=>"$mainurl?whichpage=sales",
       "Support" => "$mainurl?whichpage=support", "Contacts" => "$mainurl?whichpage=contact" );
       return $this->navbar_array;
 }

function getLeftNavBar($arr) {
$data ="<table border='1' style='background-color:yellow; width:35%'>";
$data .="<tr><td>".$arr['Home Page']."</td></tr>";
$data .="<tr><td>".$arr['Sales']."</td></tr>";
$data .="<tr><td>".$arr['Support']."</td></tr>";
$data .="<tr><td>".$arr['Contacts']."</td></tr>";
$data .="</table>";
return $data;
}

}

$carobject = new CarDealer();

$arr = $carobject->create_navbar_array();
print $carobject->getLeftNavBar($arr);
```

or need to make public your array

```
public $navbar_array = array();
```

Comment: Worked perfect. I just had to include the HTML <a href="" .... and it works perfect. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

before return $data;, print_r($data); so you can know the associative array's structure. If it didnt print on the page, try looking in view-page-source. You'll get an clear picture. I think $data should be an array, so prob it should be like 
$data['someField'] = $someValues;
And, Create or define the array before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the array values inside the getLeftNavBar() method so php knows to parse them.

try

```
 $data .="<tr><td>{ $this->navbar_array['Home Page'] }</td></tr>";
```

or

```
 $data .="<tr><td>".$this->navbar_array['Sales']."</td></tr>";
```

Why not just call create_navbar_array() inside getLeftNavBar()

```
function getLeftNavBar()   {
   $this->create_navbar_array();
  .....
```

You could rewrite it like this

```
 class CarDealer  {

   private function getUrls()  {
    return  array( 
      "Home Page"   => "$this->company_url?whichpage=home", 
      "Sales"   => "$this->company_url?whichpage=sales",
      "Support"     => "$this->company_url?whichpage=support", 
      "Contacts"    => "$this->company_url?whichpage=contact" 
    );

  }

public function getLeftNavBar() {

    $data ="<table border='1' style='background-color:yellow; width:35%'>";

    foreach($this->getUrls() as $url ) {
        $data .="<tr><td>".$url."</td></tr>";
    }

    return  $data . "</table>"; 
   }

  }


 $carobject = new CarDealer();
 print $carobject->getLeftNavBar();
```